# C# how to break after X times in a loop?

Tags: c#, loops, break

shortly, how can i stop the following code after printing 20 numbers?

Thanks

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num1 = 4;
        int num2 = 7;

        for (int i = 200; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            if ((i % num1 == 0) && (i % num2 ==0))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

I tried to write "break" after the "Console.WriteLine(i);" but then it printed only 1 number and i need 20.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to keep track of how many numbers you've printed out and then break out of the loop once you have enough:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 200; i < 2000; i++)
{
     if ((i % num1 == 0) && (i % num2 ==0))
     {
         Console.WriteLine(i);
         counter++;
         if(counter == 20)
             break;
     }
}
```

Or you can use a `for` loop with *two* conditions:

```
for (int i = 200, j= 0; i < 2000 && j < 20; i++)
{
    if ((i % num1 == 0) && (i % num2 ==0))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        j++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! your edit after Lasse V.Karlsen comment made it happend :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 200,loopCounter=0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
        if ((i % num1 == 0) && (i % num2 ==0))
        {
                 if(loopCounter == 20)
                   break;

            Console.WriteLine(i);
                    loopCounter++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the program control reaches `break` it will exit the loop in which it it running.
To ensure that the loop breaks the right point you need to check for the condition where you want to break from the loop.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num1 = 4;
    int num2 = 7;
    int counter=0
    for (int i = 200; i < 2000; i++)
    {
        if(counter>20)
           break;
        if ((i % num1 == 0) && (i % num2 ==0))
        {
            counter++;
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```